# Obtain the boot and failure history of nodes in a SLURM Cluster

Tags: slurm

I need to find out for how long each node in a SLURM cluster remains in the DOWN state every week.
That would be possible if I could access a log or history with timestamps for when nodes boot and shut down.

My current approach is to periodically issue the `scontrol show nodes` command and parse the output.
However, this solution is not robust enough to account for nodes being shutdown and rebooting in between the probes.

Any insight or clarification on how to achieve this is widely accepted.

Comment: Are you an administrator? If so, the logs can be found under `/var/log/slurm-llnl/slurmd.log`.

Comment: @Maarten-vd-Sande unfortunately I am not an administrator. I might ask for the privilege if there is no other solution. Does the log keeps records of when the nodes are rebooted in addition to when they fail?

Comment: Maybe.. In my log I get `[2019-11-28T14:59:37.268] Slurmd shutdown completing` for shutdown and `[2019-11-28T15:00:28.343] slurmd started on Thu, 28 Nov 2019 15:00:28 +0100` for startup. Not sure what the log outputs on failure (also depends on the failure ofcourse), but my guess it can be found.

Answer (score 2):

The `sacctmgr list event` command lists all events related to nodes

From the [sacctmgr manpage](https://slurm.schedmd.com/sacctmgr.html):

> event  Events like downed or draining nodes on clusters.

You can issue that command even if you are not an administrator.

Exemple output:

```
[user@clustername ~]$ sacctmgr list event
   Cluster        NodeName           TimeStart             TimeEnd  State                         Reason       User
---------- --------------- ------------------- ------------------- ------ ------------------------------ ----------
clustername node022        2019-11-19T08:55:26             Unknown  DOWN*       NO NETWORK ADDRESS FOUND slurm(555)
clustername node023        2019-11-19T08:57:08             Unknown DRAIN*               Kill task failed    root(0)
```

Comment: This seems to be easier to acquire the time when the node failed. However, as far as I could understand, there is no information available for when the nodes are rebooted after shutdown